# Не работает роут (динамический url) aiohttp на хостинге

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, aiohttp

Такая проблема, есть бот написанный на Python 3.8 с помощью библиотеки aiogram (которая использует aiohttp). Проверяю на локальной машине с помощью ngrok, Post запросы на адрес webhook приходят (https://???.ngrok.io/webhook/токен_бота). Из браузера страница так же работает. Заливаю на хостинг (сайт https://botmmfrestzone.nsu.ru) Телеграм возвращает ошибку `Wrong response from the webhook: 404 Not Found`. Пытался проверить на чистом aiohttp с помощью функции `add_route` (здесь допускаю, что мог ошибиться в проверке) динамический URL не работает. Не могли бы Вы подсказать, почему именно на хостинге не создаются динамические ссылки? (код приводить не стану, тк полезным быть может из только из самой библиотеки aiogram)

Comment: Динамические ссылки тут не при чём, проверяйте настройки nginx/Apache (не знаю, что там у Вас конкретно)

Comment: @MyZik, спасибо. Действительно в конфиг nginx надо было добавить директиву location /... { ... }